# Can't boot Windows 8.1 after update

Tags: windows, boot, uefi, gpt, bcd

I'm using linux for my day to day use. Thing is, I don't recall having any problem with my windows installation. It might be that I installed some updates and didn't restart, simply powered off and the next day booted into linux. After near a week I found I cant boot into windows, not even safe mode or recovery/reinstall partition.

> "windows failed to start" 0xc0000001 EFI Boot BCD "boot configuration data for your PC is missing or contains errors"

I don't have a system recovery disk. I *might* be able to make one with another windows 8.1 from another PC. Should it work? Is there any better option?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your windows boot manager is not working properly.

Getting a recovery disk to boot from and repairing the bootloader would be the quickest, hassle free option in repairing this.

However if this is totally not an option there are ways to repair your bootloader from Linux.

Below is a command you can run to install SysLinux which will provide you tools to repair the bootloader:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install syslinux
```

After that is installed you can run the command (Where dev/sda is your windows drive):

```
sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda
```

This is just one method, I hear it is possible from GParted also.

Heres my reference link also: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/08/repair-windows-mbr-from-ubuntu/

Comment: I'm using UEFI and so my disk has GPT instead of MBR.